# « Mettre quelqu'un au défi de » et « défier quelqu'un de » sont-ils équivalents ?

Tags: sens, verbes, locutions, synonymes, lexique

Dans un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/moyen-orient/201811/20/01-5204849-meurtre-de-khashoggi-le-roi-salmane-darabie-soutient-son-heritier.php) on rapporte les propos d'un chercheur concernant un dirigeant à l'effet qu' « [e]n fait, il défie ses critiques internationaux de mettre en pratique leur rhétorique et parie qu'ils ne le feront pas » (Kristian Ulrichsen du *Baker Institute* de l'université Rice, aux États-Unis ds. *La Presse*). Il semble que je sois davantage familier avec le tour *mettre qqn. au [défi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9fi) de* qu'avec *[défier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9fier) qqn. de*, suivi de l'infinitif. Au TLFi on introduit le sens du premier avec « mettre quelqu'un en demeure de faire quelque chose [...] » alors que pour le second on dit plutôt « inciter (quelqu'un) à faire une chose [...] » ; [Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/d%C3%A9fier/22675?q=d%C3%A9fier%20de#22555) semble présenter l'un comme synonyme de l'autre ; [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9fier) utilise *mettre en demeure de faire [...]* comme sens de *défier*.

---

- *Mettre quelqu'un au défi de/défier quelqu'un de* sont-ils synonymes, interchangeables, d'une intensité ou d'un registre différent ou autrement différents ?
- L'un est-il considérablement plus fréquent que l'autre, à l'écrit ou
  à l'oral ?

Comment: Curieux, j'ai cherché la V.O. des propos dudit chercheur. Je crois avoir trouvé mais si je peux comprendre ce qui, dans ses propos a pu être traduit ainsi, je ne le trouve pas précisément. J'y allais, il me faut l'avouer, non sans mauvais esprit... m'attendant à trouver un *to challenge* que les ignorants du fait que *challenger* est un verbe tout ce qu'il y a de plus français ont, depuis les années 70, une fichue tendance à traduire par *défier*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Défier* et *mettre au défi* sont proches mais pas toujours équivalents.

*[Défier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9fier)*, c'est manifester une attitude parfois provocante qui remet en question une hiérarchie ou une capacité de la personne, de l'animal ou de la chose défiée et affrontée. Souvent, le verbe défier n'a qu'un complément d'object direct indiquant qui ou quoi est défié :

- Il défie la mort.
- Ce loup défie le chef de la meute.
- Cette expérience défie les lois de la pesanteur.

Celui/ce qui défie est le principal acteur de la situation et montre souvent une attitude hostile.

*Mettre au [défi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9fi)*, c'est proposer à quelqu'un de relever un défi. On soumet le destinataire à une épreuve que l'on pense être au delà de ses capacités. Un complément d'objet indirect indique souvent de quelle épreuve il s'agit :

- Il l'a mis au défi de battre le record de l'heure
- Je te met au défi de faire tenir un œuf debout
- On l'a mis au défi d'apprendre l'allemand en trois mois.

La personne qui est mise au défi est le principal acteur de la situation. Celui qui propose le défi n'est pas forcément partie prenante ni forcément hostile.

Parfois, *défier* a aussi le sens de *mettre au défi*, et c'est d'ailleurs le cas dans la phrase de la question:

> il défie ses critiques internationaux de mettre en pratique leur rhétorique

La personne qui défie semble avoir une attitude plus hostile envers les critiques internationaux que s'il avait été écrit :

> il met au défi ses critiques internationaux de mettre en pratique leur rhétorique

*Mettre au défi* est improbable dans les trois premiers exemples de ma réponse :

- Il met la mort au défi.
- Ce loup met le chef de la meute au défi.
- Cette expérience met les lois de la pesanteur au défi.

On est tenté de répondre à chacune de ces phrases, *au défi de quoi ?*.

La différence est aussi manifeste quand on compare *défier* et *mettre au défi* dans des situations similaires :

Le deux phrase suivantes sont proches :

- Il l'a défié aux échecs.
- Il l'a mis au défi de le battre aux échecs.

Cependant, alors que :

- Il l'a défié de le battre aux échecs

est possible, quoique plus rare,

- Il l'a mis au défi aux échecs

ne parait pas idiomatique.

Quant à *mettre en demeure*, il ne s'agit plus en français actuel d'un défi, mais de l'expression d'une contrainte forte à effectuer quelque chose dans un délai donné. Cette notion de délai est absente du défi.

Alors que quand on met quelqu'un au défi, on s'attend à ce qu'il ne réussisse pas, quand on met quelqu'un en demeure, on s'attend à ce qu'il le fasse. Une mise en demeure n'est donc pas quelque chose que l'on relève comme un défi mais plutôt une injonction à laquelle on doit se plier, encore qu'une personne mise en demeure pourrait défier la personne qui lui présente en ne s'y soumettant pas.

Comment: Sans mettre en doute la pertinence de cette réponse dans son ensemble, je crois que l'association faite ici de *défier* avec *mettre au défi* pêche un poil du fait de l'omission dans l'analyse du pronominal (se défier). Un autre point qui me semble important à observer mais que je ne saurais là maintenant analyser est la proximité **dé**fier / **mé**fier. Bref! (Mais je ne saurais l'être et encore moins prétendre faire une meilleure réponse que la tienne) il me semble difficile, pour cette analyse de ne pas partir de *fier*, vedette à laquelle renvoit au demeurant le DHLF pour *défier*.

Comment: @aCOSwt Non pas que je me *méfie*, mais en toute bonne *foi*, je te *confie* sans *perfidie* que je préfère rester dans ma réponse *fidèle* à la question posée qui se limite à « *défier* » et « mettre au *défi* » plutôt que me *fier* à tes *confidences* sur le pronominal *se défier* assez *confidentiel* de nos jours, et inclure dans ma réponse tous les dérivés et apparentés de *fidēs* comme par exemple *fiançailles* que l'on pourrait *fédérer* sous la bannière de l'hypothétique *bʰeydʰ-* ...

Comment: Je te comprends très bien. Je réaffirme que je ne saurais probablement pas faire mieux Mais... tout en étant persuadé qu'on en loupe les 3/4 qui, sans aller dans tous les apparentés, permettraient d'entrevoir une explication totalement rationnelle.

Comment: @aCOSwt N'hésitez pas à rédiger une réponse complémentaire ! Merci !

Answer (score 0):

« Mettre en demeure » est apparemment trop fort; dans le droit français ce terme signifie clairement « imposer par voie légale »; j'ai la même impression que les deux formes sont équivalentes; cela trouve confirmation dans une traduction de dictionnaire (Harrap), qui pour « **mettre au défi** » donne « **to defy** », « **to dare** » ; la traduction de « **to defy** » en français donne dans le même dictionnaire « **mettre au défi », « défier** ». Je tendrais à croire la compréhension de ceux qui ne voient pas de différence comme étant juste.

Il faut cependant considérer que dans certaines situations, ces défis qui sont autrement souvent lancés en tant que simple façon de parler, peuvent être des défis formels que le parti mis au défi se voit obliger de relever. Il y a peut être dans ce contexte une prépondérance d'utilisation de « **mettre au défi** ».